# CCtray unable to connect to dashboard

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cctray

I am using CCnet 1.6 and cctray 1.6. On the build server, the tray works properly using localhost. Remotely though, I am not able to connect the tray to the dashboard. The dashboard URL works great, but when I put that into the cctray settings, I get a 500 internal server error.

This worked up until I had to move CCnet from defaultwebsite to its own. Did I miss something when I changed it over?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is similar to a question [I just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9594074/1141876) but if you want to persist with remoting (but may not work so well over the Internet with firwalls and the like)

1. Open your dashboard.config (likely path is C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\dashboard.config)
2. Find the port number your dashboard is connecting to the server on (eg: 21234)
3. In CC Tray, select remoting and enter **hostname:portnumber** (eg: mycruiseserver:21234)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the CCNET server is part of your local network this should work:

- Select .NET remoting as connection type
- Specify the CCNET server's address only by its IP address (instead of using the dashboard URL)

Comment: So, I tried the IP of the server as .NET remoting. The error is as follows:  Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.210.0.14:21234

Comment: I had the same issue, but after configuring a firewall rule for port 21234 to allow inbound access things worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching off your firewall, it may be that you havn't opened your port.

Then, use the `buildserver:port` method (remotely via **.NET**).

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my problem (v1.8.3 for my installation).

I set the name attribute in the `<server />` tag in dashboard.config to match the hostname. I'm not sure if that is required but that is the first thing I tried.

Then I inspected the bindings for the site that the dashboard is hosted under in IIS. The hostname for the binding was blank, so I changed it to the hostname for the site.

I noticed that the CCNet machine's event log had exceptions logged for unknown domain when I was trying to connect CCTray to it.

When I went to add a build server in CCTray on the remote machine, I selected via dashboard and it worked for me.